# Can I run a "standard", non-Android, Java app on Android?

Tags: android

In my case I want to write an app which is totally symetrical (not client-server) with identical functionality at two PCs, one a 'standard' Windows or Linux box and the other an Android slate.

Can I run the same program on both or do I nneed to wrap it in an Android package for persmissioons, etc?

The two PCs will communciate by TCP/IP, sort of peer-to-peer, but I suspect that as a generic question this might be of interest to many.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you cannot run an independent java application on Android. Android applications are compiled to dalvik bytecode and really are just written in java but not run on the java vm (Android does not have a java vm). However you can create a jar library that can be consumed by both a desktop and android application and that should provide reuse of platform independent code.

Comment: You also need it for your user interface, permissions, so it can be distributed/installed like a normal Android application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** run command-line Java programs on an Android device.  An example of a simple "hello, world" program is [described here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/hello-world.html;hb=HEAD).

As noted previously, though, you can't use the Android framework for UI, and unless you have a rooted phone you won't be able to install it in /data or access "protected" features like talking to the Internet.

Comment: Please note, even in the link posted you are still not running a java application on Android (there is no JVM) you are compiling the java into a dalvik executable to run on the dalvik vm.

Comment: You are correct, of course.  I should have said, "you can run command-line programs written in the Java programming language", which isn't the same thing.